# How to find out which service is sending an email?

Tags: postfix

Last week I installed Postfix (only for sending from server) on my Ubuntu 18.04 server. I didn't prepare any service for sending yet, because I want to clear something. In /var/log/mail.log I see many records, but I can't find which service is trying to send an email.

```
Dec  1 14:57:45 localhost postfix/qmgr[11433]: 5F1BB4122F: from=<root@website.eu>, size=5664, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec  1 14:57:45 localhost postfix/qmgr[11433]: 853C441246: from=<root@website.eu>, size=11049, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec  1 14:57:45 localhost postfix/smtp[20453]: connect to website.eu[127.0.1.1]:25: Connection refused
Dec  1 14:57:45 localhost postfix/smtp[20453]: 853C441246: to=<root@website.eu>, orig_to=<root>, relay=none, delay=193627, delays=193627/0.01/0.11/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (
connect to website.eu[127.0.1.1]:25: Connection refused)
Dec  1 14:57:45 localhost postfix/smtp[20452]: connect to website.eu[127.0.1.1]:25: Connection refused
Dec  1 14:57:45 localhost postfix/smtp[20452]: 5F1BB4122F: to=<root@website.eu>, orig_to=<root>, relay=none, delay=197858, delays=197858/0.02/0.18/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (
connect to website.eu[127.0.1.1]:25: Connection refused)
Dec  1 16:07:45 localhost postfix/qmgr[11433]: 5F1BB4122F: from=<root@website.eu>, size=5664, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec  1 16:07:45 localhost postfix/qmgr[11433]: 853C441246: from=<root@website.eu>, size=11049, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec  1 16:07:45 localhost postfix/smtp[20811]: connect to website.eu[127.0.1.1]:25: Connection refused
Dec  1 16:07:45 localhost postfix/smtp[20812]: connect to website.eu[127.0.1.1]:25: Connection refused
Dec  1 16:07:45 localhost postfix/smtp[20811]: 5F1BB4122F: to=<root@website.eu>, orig_to=<root>, relay=none, delay=202058, delays=202058/0.02/0.03/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (
connect to website.eu[127.0.1.1]:25: Connection refused)
Dec  1 16:07:45 localhost postfix/smtp[20812]: 853C441246: to=<root@website.eu>, orig_to=<root>, relay=none, delay=197827, delays=197827/0.02/0.03/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (
connect to website.eu[127.0.1.1]:25: Connection refused)
```

Any idea what can cause this? I checked cron jobs, but they don't start at the times recorded. Is there any setting for more detailed logging?

Comment: Yes there is more verbose log settings, about authentication. But, First you could look at the deferred email content in the mail queue `postcat -vq 5F1BB4122F`

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot because with your help I can see that the time wasn't the same and it was really from cronjob - but it was a deferred email. And it tries and tries ... now I delete it and it looks ok.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to change the `witch` to `which` in the title.